# Reading data from a text file, parsing it and storing it in an array in shell script

Tags: bash, parsing, shell

I have a text file with matrices

A: 1, 2, 3, 4

B: 2, 4, 6, 8; 1, 2, 5, 6

C: 8, 6, 4, 2; 1, 2, 3, 4; 1, 3, 5, 7

and I want to read this file in shell script, store these matrices in different arrays and then use these arrays for further computation (addition and subtraction only). 
Here is my code:

```
#! /bin/bash
R=`awk -F'[^0-9]+' '{$1=$1; print;}' testfile.txt`
echo $R;
```

this gives me an output in this form:

1 2 3 4 2 4 6 8 1 2 5 6 8 6 4 2 1 2 3 4 1 3 5 7

I tried using loops to put these in different arrays but that didn't work for some reason.
Can anyone help me with this?

(i am new to shell scripting so a little explanation with your code solution would be really helpful. thanks)

Comment: Do those semicolons mean anything special?  What exactly is the data structure here?

Comment: The semicolons are different rows of the matrix.

Comment: as you're using awk in your solution already, why not just solve the whole thing in awk. Awk is designed to solve problems like this, although indexes into matriccies (sp) occasionally require some head scratching. If you're going to use this knowledge going forward, learning awk is definitely worth the time. Reading http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html#uh-23 (and the whole article) will be time well spent. Good luck.

Comment: thanks. I was just reading this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the Laws of Programming is that parsing input is often more difficult than the entire remainder of the exercise.

To get started, you can try using either `cut` or the [Internal Field Separator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/918886/split-string-based-on-delimiter-in-bash) several times on each line.

First use `:` as the delimiter to separate the array name from the values.
Then use `;` as the delimiter to separate the rows.
Finally, use `,` as the delimiter to get the individual values.

Answer (score 0):

This will store the matrix values in the arrays A, B and C:

```
IFS+=,\;
eval `
while read name numbers
do  if [ $name ]
    then    echo "${name%:}=($numbers)"
    fi
done <testfile.txt
`
```

This will output the different arrays, just for checking purposes:

```
echo ${A[*]}
echo ${B[*]}
echo ${C[*]}
```

Since bash provides only one-dimensional arrays, we have to compute an index given the row size, e. g.

```
row=2; col=3
echo ${C[$row*4+$col]}
```